# Copying data with command button without duplicates in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I made a command button to tranfer data from one worksheet to another, if conditions are met. I would like to ask how I can prevent the button from making duplicates if I use it multiple times. For example: if I add additional data to the first sheet that I need copied. Down below is the code i used for the button.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
A = Worksheets("All").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To A

If Worksheets("All").Cells(i, 3).Value = "X" Then

    Worksheets("All").Rows(i).Copy
    Worksheets("Lending").Activate
    b = Worksheets("Lending").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Lending").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Worksheets("All").Activate

    End If
   Next

 Application.CutCopyMode = False

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Many ways.  **1:** Clear the target sheet and redo the whole table. **2:** Add `ID` column to original data; check last ID in target before starting the copy and start the testing after that ID.  **3:** Copy from beginning of table, but run `RemoveDuplicates` after the operation.  #2 will probably be the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use remove duplicate procedure. I do some edits you can see below:

Sub MyCammand()

```
Dim AllSheet As Worksheet
Dim LendSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim RowCnt As Integer
Dim DestRow As Integer

Set AllSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("All")
Set LendSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Lending")

With AllSheet
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    DestRow = LendSheet.Range("A" & LendSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For RowCnt = 2 To LastRow
        If .Cells(RowCnt, 3).Value = "X" Or .Cells(RowCnt, 3).Value = "x" Then
            LendSheet.Rows(DestRow).Value = .Rows(RowCnt).Value
            DestRow = DestRow + 1
        End If
    Next
End With
'..... Remove Duplicates
Dim LastCol As String
With LendSheet
    LastCol = Split(.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Address, "$")(1)
    .Range("A:" & LastCol).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), Header:=xlYes
End With
```

End Sub